# Creating correct label data in lightgbm

Tags: python, classification, lightgbm

I try to use **Lightgbm classifier** for document classification Dataset contains 6 different document classes  labeled from 12 to 19 and two labels are skipped

Here is the example of y_train values:

```
y_train = df_train['CategoryID'].values

and unique values are in the array:

array([18, 12, 19, 15, 17, 13])
```

The same is for y_valid.

When I try to train the model

```
train_data = lgb.Dataset(x_train, label=y_train)
valid_data = lgb.Dataset(x_valid, label=y_valid)
param = {'objective': 'multiclass',
         'num_class': 6,
         'learning_rate': 0.08,
         'num_leaves': 5,
         'max_depth': -1,
         'seed': 381,
         'bagging_seed': 381,
         'feature_fraction_seed': 381,
         'metric': 'multi_error',
         'bagging_fraction': 0.2,
         'bagging_freq': 1,
         'feature_fraction': 0.5,
         'early_stopping': 1000,
         'verbosity': 1}
bst = lgb.train(param, train_data, num_round, valid_sets=[train_data, valid_data], verbose_eval=100)
```

I get the following error

```
LightGBMError: Label must be in [0, 6), but found 18 in label
```

Any Idea how to solve how to change class labeling?

Comment: did you try to pass labels without unique? lgb.Dataset(x_train, label=df_train['CategoryID'].values)

Comment: Hi Marco, actually I haven't passed y_train as unique, I just wanted to explain what kind of unique labels I have in dataset. I think that solution is in using LabelEncoder for y_train

Comment: sorry but the above code is a little bit misleading... yes, a solution can be labelenc